# How to save data in the list for cordova android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-2.7.0

My project contains listview  and I have added the data dynamically.My question is "How can I save data in the list for cordova android .Any ides? Thanks in advance

Comment: if you are using angular js then i think you have to create global object and store the list data in that global object and retrieve global object from html that will be the easy for you. thanks:-)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..Iam not using angular js in my project.

Comment: Please can any one of you help me,What i need to do?

Comment: Please add the relevant code from your project. It will save time for people asking what you are using and how you are implementing. Some questions you could solve by showing code are: are you using a native listview? how are you obtaining the data? are you using phonegap build service or building locally? if local, are you using the CLI or did you download the zip? thanks